# Error while updating property 'src' of a view managed by: RCTImageView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, android-emulator, react-native

I'm getting the error above when selecting an image using React Native:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.selectImage.bind(image.uri)}>

selectImage(uri) {
  this.setState({
    selected: uri,
  });
}
```

However, I'm getting this error only in my local emulator. If I use `rnplay` it works fine.

Comment: Do you resolved this ?

Comment: @LirooPierre nope, I ended up moving to the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/).